# Is there a GEM to make a rails app work like an FTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ftp

I have an app that stores products that get loaded up to other sites.  Typically I get the product data via REST in the form of CSV files.  These get stored in TMP, parsed and imported.

I however have a client who now wants to send me files via FTP, but at the same time doesn't want to use an external FTP.

So.  I'm wondering if there's a GEM to make my rails app respond to FTP commands. Something that could present a table the same way that FTP presents files.

Yes I know I should go back and say "ha haa Haaaa!", but mine is not to reason why, mine is to do, or die.

I could likely role my own, but if there's a GEM someone knows of that would be most helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There maybe (but I doubt it). However, Heroku will only accept incoming requests on Port 80 or if you're using an SSL-Endpoint that will accept requests on port 443. So with Heroku, if you even found a gem it would be impossible to use FTP since that relies on port 20/21 as a standard.

I've done something similar but not using FTP, rather having the client place files on Amazon S3 and then have my Heroku app list contents of a folder on S3.